# Powershell Sent the email with HTML table in the message body

Tags: html

The email I sent contain HTML table.

The html table saved in the $MailBody

```
$MailBody = @{<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#customers {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

#customers td, #customers th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#customers th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Königlich Essen</td>
    <td>Philip Cramer</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>North/South</td>
    <td>Simon Crowther</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris spécialités</td>
    <td>Marie Bertrand</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
}
```

This is the code for sending the email along with the HTML table

```
$Msg = @{
to          = ($MailtTo -split ';')
from        = $MailFrom
BodyAsHtml  = $True
Subject     = $MailSubject
Body        = $MailBody
smtpserver  = $SmtpServer
Credential  = $Credentials
}

Send-MailMessage @Msg
```

I found that the view of the table from Window Outlook is different from the Web Browser Outlook.

All the HTML table column are shrink in Window Outlook.

I wish to view the HTML table in the Window Outlook same as it looks from HTML

Is there any solution to solve this problem ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Powershell and everything to do with how the HTML is rendered. I've edited the tags accordingly.

Comment: @alroc But the html code when I save into html file and open it at browser it show perfectly as I want to. Only when I open in the Window Outlook all the column are shrink.

Comment: Here is the answer [Sending Formatted HTML email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648774/sending-formatted-html-email) ,the reason being is most email clients don't render css style sheet in the header properly. They need to be inline. However, inline style works better but still won't be as good as browsers e.g. gradient color is not supported at least in Outlook 2016 or Outlook Web (OWA)